# go build ld: warning: ignoring file xxx/libmd5tool.a, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file f

Tags: macos, go, .a

macos monterey12.6

Trying to go build project

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/xxx/Documents/go-repo/src/scbapi/vendor/apiutil/lib/libmd5tool.a, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x21 0x3C 0x61 0x72 0x63 0x68 0x3E 0x0A 0x2F 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 )
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_get_param_sign", referenced from:
      __cgo_ad8a3ace256a_C2func_get_param_sign in _x002.o
      __cgo_ad8a3ace256a_Cfunc_get_param_sign in _x002.o
     (maybe you meant: __cgo_ad8a3ace256a_C2func_get_param_sign, __cgo_ad8a3ace256a_Cfunc_get_param_sign )
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```